# get the next key in array in php foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a select box and wanting to get the key of the next value in array to go with the option here is my code

```
<select>

<?php foreach ($make as $key => $make):?>
      <option value="<?php echo next($key);//not correct ?> - <?php echo $key; ?>"> <?php echo $make; ?></option>
<?php endforeach;
```

Here is the array

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Brand
    [1] => Alfa Romeo
    [123] => Alpina
    [142] => Aston Martin
    [152] => Audi
    [619] => Bentley
    [640] => BMW
    [1122] => Buick

)
```

Comment: Are the keys numeric and nicely ordered

Comment: Just out of interest, what do you want to happen on the last iteration of the loop, when the "next" key doesn't exist?

Comment: And WHY would the `value` attribute want to contain something you cannot easily use to address to the correct value

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question but it really sounds like a case for re-thinking your array structure rather than trying to do what you described

Comment: Yes they are numerical index

Comment: @kariuki - based on the array you added, the accepted answer will not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<select>

<?php 
foreach ($make as $key => $make):
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $key + 1; ?> - <?php echo $key; ?>"> 
<?php echo $make; 
?>
</option>
<?php 
endforeach;
```

Just increment the `$key` by 1, and you will have the next array element if the keys are in order and are numeric.

Comment: Are you sure this code runs with `foreach ($make as $key => $make):`?

Comment: this will not work for associative array.  It will also throw return a non-existent key on the final iteration since `$key + 1` doesn't exist in the array at that point.  It may be what the OP wanted but it doesn't "*get the next key in array in php foreach loop*"

Comment: The OP stated his keys were numeric, so it's answers his question, but thanks, good job.

Answer (score 3):

This will work with an associative array as well as numerically indexed:

```
<?php foreach ($make as $key => $value):?>
    <?php next($make); ?>
    <option value="<?php echo key($make); ?> - <?php echo $key; ?>"> <?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note, it's confusing and probably a bad idea to use the same variable name for iterating as the array.  so instead of `foreach ($make as $key => $make)` I did `foreach ($make as $key => $value)` here.

The code above simply advances the pointer on the array and then gets the key for your option value using `key()`.  Since there is no *next key* on the final array element, the value will be empty.

Comment: Nice solution, I see your solution now, I think this way is best answer...so that I will vote for you...

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP unaccepted my answer but thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve your issue with a lot of solution, but if you have an assoiatve array or none order array or not numirc, you can use this:

```
<?php
$array = ["a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, 1 => "aa"];

next($array);
$key = key($array);
echo $key;
prev($array);
$key = key($array);
echo $key;
```

Else, if array is ordered and numeric you can use `$key + 1`;

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get key of next element is to use array_search of next element of array e.g.

```
<?php foreach ($makers as $key => $make):?>
  <option value="<?php echo array_search( next($makers), $makers );"> <?php echo $make; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this function. it finds current key of given value in the array, and from that found key's position, you can get next/previous key with $increment
Ex: when `$increment=1`, it finds next key
when `$increment=2`, it finds 2 next key
when `$increment=-1`, it finds 1 previous key, and so on.

```
function sov_find_key($findvalue, $array, $increment) {
    reset($array);
    $key = array_search($findvalue, $array);
    
    if ($key === false || $key === 0){
        return false;
    }
    
    if ($increment === 0){
        return $key;
    }
    
    $isNegative = $increment < 0 ? true:false;
    $increment = abs($increment);
    
    while(key($array) !== $key) {
        next($array);
    }
    
    $x=0;
    while($x < $increment) {
        if( $isNegative ){
            prev($array);
        } else {
            next($array);
        }
        $x++;
    }
    
    return key($array);
}
```

DEMO: https://3v4l.org/CSSmR